# Всплывающая подсказка при клике на элемент прижалась к краю экрана. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Всплывающая подсказка при клике на элемент прижалась к краю экрана, а нужно появление непосредственно под элементом, на который кликаешь. Не пойму в чем ошибка.
Код js непосредственно:

```
const allTips = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('has-tooltip'));

function toolTipsActive(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let deletableElement = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip tooltip_active")[0];
    if (deletableElement) {
        deletableElement.remove();
    }
    let tipText = this.title;
    this.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<div class="tooltip tooltip_active">${tipText}</div>`);
}



for (let i = 0; i < allTips.length; i++) {
    const element = allTips[i];
    element.addEventListener('click', toolTipsActive);
}
```

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: За расположение элекментов на экране в числе прочего css отвечает

Comment: .header {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.has-tooltip {
  color: #000;
  background: yellow;
}

.has-tooltip:hover {
  color: red;
}

.tooltip {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.tooltip_active {
  display: block;
}

Comment: @Артур почитайте, пожалуйста, что такое вообще `position`, как минимум в MDN должна быть описана работа этой пропорции.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/position